Force WinForms ListBox to recalculate all item heights in Mono Project
I'm trying to run a winforms project through mono and found a bug/difference with the ListBox implementation.
I've used the answer to this Question to increase the height of individual items and wordwarp, which worked great on Windows. Running the code through mono, causes text to overflow beyond the bottom of the ListBox and become unscrollable.
Essentially if 1 of the items in the collection is double height, you can no longer see the last item at the bottom of the list, and you can't scroll it into view.
It looks like either the scrollbar is using a fixed "item.height x items.count" type logic, or that Graphics.DrawString() is drawing out of the listbox's bottom bounds. The MeasureItem() event seems to trigger correctly every time a new item gets added to the list, but the total height of all items in the list is bound to a fixed size multiplied by items. I've been looking at ways to force a correct draw or height calculation, but simple things I've tried havent worked so far (adding & removing items, redrawing the listbox, changing its size after all items have been added,etc)
I've also looked at a few other questions here and Google but I haven't managed to come up with a fix.
    private void lstMeasureItemHandler(object sender,MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        if (listBox.Items.Count <= 0) return;

        e.ItemHeight = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), listBox.Font, listBox.Width).Height;
    }

    private void lstDrawItemHandler(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
        if (listBox.Items.Count <= 0) return;

        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);
    }

    private  void ModListbox(ref ListBox listBox)
    {
        listBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        listBox.MeasureItem += lstMeasureItemHandler;
        listBox.DrawItem += lstDrawItemHandler;
    }


How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item?

@Jimi Thanks for your reply. Your solution is beautiful and you are a star! Unfortunately it has the same issue running through mono. As soon as it gets filled with text, you can't see or scroll down to the last item anymore

@Jimi Actually it seems even more pronounced as almost half the lines are no longer visible or scrollable. I made a little sample app with a standard list, your multiline list,  and a list using the event handlers in the question. I've also added buttons to add 1 single line item to all the lists, and to add 1 multiline item to all the lists. All 3 lists have the exact same scroll positions and bounds. The standard listbox shows all the items (25), the multiline ones only show 16 and 21 items respectively

That was for testing the result with code that produces a known behavior. It appears there's a small bug in the UpdateVerticalScrollBar() method in the ListBox.cs file of the Mono implementation, where only the default Item's height is considered, and this affect the vertical ScrollBar's LargeChange value. You can probably modify the source code to consider the value returned by GetItemHeight() instead (not tested)

Thanks for the feedback! I was hoping for something simpler but i guess I'll try recompiling mono. On the bright side, maybe i can fix some other bugs i've found
